# Can you move things inside of a grid?

Tags: html, css

I just learned grids in CSS and I don't really know everything of course. That's why I'm here :D
And my question is if I could move these circles (picture 1) so they are on line 3? So they are centered on line 3. And some are 50% on grid 4 (or 6) and 50% on grid 7 (or 9)

Because "top: ;" doesn't work in grids I assume.

I already did it without the grid but it seems easier to do it with grids and with less code.

Picture 1: https://prnt.sc/lfUtL5QX1W4w

And at the and I want it to look like this: https://prnt.sc/qr9grOfoqqCo

```css
body {
  background: #62306D;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid-item-5,
.grid-item-7,
.grid-item-8,
.grid-item-9 {
  background: #F7EC7D;
}

.grid-item-4,
.grid-item-6 {
  background: #AA445F;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item-5">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item-6">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item-7">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item-8">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item-9">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also it's not clear what you are trying to do. Which "Line 3" and what do you mean by "on line 3"?

Comment: @Paulie_D I *think* the OP wants to slide the circles downward so they occupy half of cell 4/7 and 6/9

Comment: I have added pictures so I thought it is visible? @Paulie_D

Comment: Well a `transform` would do it, or, even better, a 6 row grid, not 3.

Comment: @isherwood I can't add them anymore because my reputation is under 10 so I'm not allowed to post any pictures on the site. That's why I use links for that

Comment: Look up `grid-area` for the children and make a 6 row grid.

Comment: @Paulie_D I just needed the "transform" totally forgot to use this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the cell numbers in the CSS rule with the border radius. To shift a circle you can use [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [translateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY()).

```css
body {
  background: #62306D;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item-7,
.grid-item-9 {
  background: #AA445F;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.grid-item-8:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item-1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item-3">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item-4">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item-5">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item-6">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item-7">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item-8">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item-9">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It wasn't the thing I wanted to achieve. I got it now just had to use "transform: translate(0px, 50px);